# How to clear cache of latest select query that was run? (or prevent a select query from caching)

Tags: sql-server, caching, sql-server-2012, query-optimization, sqlcachedependency

I am using MS SQL Server 2012. I am trying to see the optimization in the server so I can't just clear everything.

This [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174283.aspx) didn't work for me. (or this [example](http://sqlserverplanet.com/optimization/comparing-query-performance))

Any suggestions how I can select the query and clear the cache afterwards? 
(or prevent it from caching would be better)

**EDIT:**
Most desired outcome is testing the select query like it's running for the very first time.

Answer (score 0):

You can query `sys.dm_exec_connections` to get a handle to last executed query for a given connection, and then evict that plan with `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`. Make sure you do this on another connection.

Alternatively, use `WITH RECOMPILE` or `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` to not cache the plan at all:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlmeditation/archive/2013/01/01/is-it-really-quot-recompile-quot-or-a-quot-private-temporary-compile-quot.aspx

Comment: I am trying this in my local machine for now. When I run the following:

`CHECKPOINT;
GO
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;
GO
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;
GO
DBCC FREESESSIONCACHE;
GO`

It first takes a minute for the query to finish, when I run the **DBCC FREEPROCCACHE** or the **RECOMPILE** stuffs, the second time queried takes less than a second.. Is there something else being saved other than cache that makes it so quick? (Less 1 sec on 2nd run)

Comment: Yes, the data is cached, repeat the CHECKPOINT / DROPCLEANBUFFERS routine every time.

Comment: Locally that is okay, in the server however, I can't just clear all the cache.. Is there a way making that specific query run like it's queried for the first time?

Comment: No, you can't clear just selected pages from data buffer, only the selected plans. But you should pay attention to logical reads when you apply `SET STATISTICS IO ON` and also the CPU time from `SET STATISTICS TIME ON`.